# Haskell - spliting a list into several lists

Tags: list, haskell, fold

Given a sorted list of tuples, return a list containing list of tuples where each list of tuples adheres to the conditions:

1) for each (a,b) and (c,d) in the list of tuples, a == c

2) the second element of each tuple must be the previous+1, so for [(a, y1), (b, y2), (c, y3)] => y2 = y1+1; y3 = y2 + 1

Example:

Input

> ex = [(0,2),(1,0),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,4)]

Output

> groupTogether ex = [[(0,2)], [(1,0)], [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)],[(2,4)]]

This must be implemented using fold.

My Implementation:

```
groupTogether :: [(Integer,Integer)]-> [[(Integer,Integer)]]
groupTogether [] = []
groupTogether pairs@(x:xs) = foldr (\(a,b) acc -> if ( (a == fst(last(last(acc)))) && (b == fst(last(last(acc)))) ) 
                                                  then (a,b) : (last(last(acc))) 
                                                  else [(a,b)] : ((last(acc)))
                                   ) [[]] pairs
```

The error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @PeterHall Does it really matter? I posted my effort in trying to solve the question, it's not like I just wanted the implementation without trying to solve it first

Comment: @PeterHall And to answer your question, no, it is not homework.

Comment: [Official-ish guidelines on asking and answering (potential) homework questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Indeed it doesn't really matter; if it's a good question, it's a good question regardless of its homework status.

Comment: @GeorgeCernat It might not matter too much. But someone might answer your question differently if they knew it was homework. For example, explain the error and point you to the problem, rather than giving a complete code solution.

Comment: @PeterHall Imho, explaining the error and pointing you to the problem AS WELL AS giving a complete code solution is the best type of answer, anyway

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I think you are missing the fact that the image I posted is not the code, the code is already posted into the question's description, the image contains in fact the error given, which, in this particular, for someone knowing haskell, it's a lot easier to figure what the problem is by looking at the exact error. I think that coping and pasting that error into the question descrption would have definitely been much less readable. You should consider your down-vote

Comment: @MichaelLitchard Nevertheless, thank you for sharing the reason of your downvote, instead of just down-voting.

Comment: @GeorgeCernat Or, you could just conform to standard practice and cut and paste your error, which does include code, like every one else. It's not about this question in particular but the quality of the site as a whole. Why is your question special?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I stand by what I side, there's always exceptions and in this case, this was the better thing to do, imo. Of course, you can disagree :)

Comment: @MichaelLitchard but, for the sake of argument, I have two questions. 1) Would you have removed the down-vote had I deleted the image and put instead the text version of the error and 2) would it have been clearer to you if the error was in text rather than like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when use `foldr`, the right-hand side elements of given list will be processed first. For example, the list:

```
[(0,2),(1,0),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,4)]
```

when processes 3rd element `(1,2)`, the processed elements, i.e. `acc`

```
acc = [[(1,3),(1,4)],[(2,4)]]
```

so, the element need to be compared with `(1,2)` is `(1,3)`. that is `head (head acc)` not `last (last acc)`. Moreover, instead of using `head`, it can be accessed through pattern matching as:

```
(pairs@((x, y):xs):xss)
```

and compare to `(a, b)`:

```
a == x && b == (y - 1)
```

and group them together if the condition is met:

```
((a, b):pairs):xss
```

Moreover, it is more readable to define a step function instead of using anonymous function, since it need to handle the right-most element with the empty list as:

```
step p [] = [[p]]
```

Once the first element has been processed, `acc = [[p]]` and never to be empty list in subsequent steps and hence match the pattern defined above. Here is how the step function be defined:

```
groupTogether = foldr step []
    where step p [] = [[p]]
          step p@(a, b) acc@(pairs@((x, y):xs):xss) 
                | a == x && b == (y - 1) = (p:pairs):xss
                | otherwise              = [p]:acc
```

The step function is straight forward when understand how `foldr` operate. Finally, as a side note, the declare:

```
groupTogether [] = []
```

is not necessary. Since `foldr` will return its second argument when pass an empty list to `groupTogether`, in this example, return `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
[(a,b)] : last acc
```

we have:

```
     acc :: [[(Integer, Integer)]] -- presumed
last acc ::  [(Integer, Integer)]
[(a,b)]  ::  [(Integer, Integer)]
```

So `[(a,b)]` has the right type to be the first element of an `[[(Integer, Integer)]]`, but `last acc` does not have the right type to be the tail of an `[[(Integer, Integer)]]`.

In

```
(a,b) : last (last acc)
```

we have:

```
           acc  :: [[(Integer, Integer)]] -- presumed
      last acc  ::  [(Integer, Integer)]
last (last acc) ::   (Integer, Integer)
(a,b)           ::   (Integer, Integer)
```

So `(a,b)` does not have the right type to be the first element of an `[[(Integer, Integer)]]`, and `last (last acc)` does not have the right type to be the tail of an `[[(Integer, Integer)]]`.

I leave the fixes up to you; hopefully this elucidates the meaning of the error enough that you can make progress.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, I have up-voted it, but will not accept it as an answer, as it is a partial answer.